# React.js - how to navigate to other domain?

Tags: reactjs, navigation

I'm working on editor where user can set link to another website , for example `stackoverflow.com`. If user set this url to `<a>` element and then click on this link he will be navigated to `http://myapp.com/stackoverflow.com` but not to `http://stackoverflow.com`. I supposed that this is caused by changed default behavior of  element. 
How can i make this link external? if user will copy url from browser and paste he will paste `http://stackoverflow.com` and hence everything will works fine. But in case he manually enter `stackoverflow.com` nothing will work fine.
P.s. i also would like to make each  element with attribute `target="_blank"` so, i assume that i can't navigate programatically 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `<a>`'s `href` attribute to the full url, not just `stackoverflow.com`:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" />
```

Otherwise it's treated as a relative url.

Add a check to see whether your users input the url as `stackoverflow.com`, and if they do, change it to `http://stackoverflow.com` before setting the `href` attribute.

Didn't get your other question about programmatic navigation, but if you want a link to open in a new window/tab, use

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. I'll try to implement ur suggestion. But what about those cases where websites use https:// instead of http:// ? Does it matter ?
About other question: i mean how can i programatically open new tab\window with target url

Comment: Doing <a href="h t t p s ://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" /> (with "https") should also work. Try it. To navigate to a url programmatically, you could use window.open("h t t p s ://stackoverflow.com", "_blank"); or just window.open("h t t p s ://stackoverflow.com"); -- both will open the url in a new browser window/tab (had to add spaces in "h t t p s" to prevent the url from being converted to an <a> tag in the comments, remove them in your code, just use "https" without spaces)